# pthread_cond_timedwait returns one second early

Tags: linux, pthreads, glibc

The program below produces this output:

```
$ ./test_condvar 9000
1343868189.623067126 1343868198.623067126 FIRST
1343868197.623132345 1343868206.623132345 TIMEOUT
1343868205.623190120 1343868214.623190120 TIMEOUT
1343868213.623248184 1343868222.623248184 TIMEOUT
1343868221.623311549 1343868230.623311549 TIMEOUT
1343868229.623369718 1343868238.623369718 TIMEOUT
1343868237.623428856 1343868246.623428856 TIMEOUT
```

Note that reading across rows shows a time delta of the intended 9 seconds, but reading down columns show that `pthread_cond_timedwait` returns ETIMEDOUT in 8 seconds.

pthread lib is glibc 2.12. running Red Hat EL6. `uname -a` shows `2.6.32-131.12.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 23 11:13:45 CDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

it looks like `pthread_cond_timedwait` relies on `lll_futex_timed_wait` for the timeout behavior.

Any ideas on where else to search for an explanation?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t mtx_attr;
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    pthread_condattr_t cond_attr;
    pthread_cond_t cond;

    int milliseconds;
    const char *res = "FIRST";

    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        fputs ( "must specify interval in milliseconds", stderr );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    milliseconds = atoi ( argv[1] );

    pthread_mutexattr_init ( &mtx_attr );
    pthread_mutexattr_settype ( &mtx_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL );
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared ( &mtx_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE );

    pthread_mutex_init ( &mtx, &mtx_attr );
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy ( &mtx_attr );

#ifdef USE_CONDATTR
    pthread_condattr_init ( &cond_attr );
    if ( pthread_condattr_setclock ( &cond_attr, CLOCK_REALTIME ) != 0 )
    {
        fputs ( "pthread_condattr_setclock failed", stderr );
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    pthread_cond_init ( &cond, &cond_attr );
    pthread_condattr_destroy ( &cond_attr );
#else
    pthread_cond_init ( &cond, NULL );
#endif

    for (;;)
    {
        struct timespec now, ts;
            clock_gettime ( CLOCK_REALTIME, &now );

        ts.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + milliseconds / 1000;
            ts.tv_nsec = now.tv_nsec + (milliseconds % 1000) * 1000000;
        if (ts.tv_nsec > 1000000000)
        {
            ts.tv_nsec -= 1000000000;
            ++ts.tv_sec;
        }

        printf ( "%ld.%09ld %ld.%09ld %s\n", now.tv_sec, now.tv_nsec,
                 ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec, res );

        pthread_mutex_lock ( &mtx );
        if ( pthread_cond_timedwait ( &cond, &mtx, &ts ) == ETIMEDOUT )
            res = "TIMEOUT";
        else
            res = "OTHER";
        pthread_mutex_unlock ( &mtx );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a [Linux kernel bug](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1207.1/01408.html) triggered by the insertion of a leap second on July 1st this year, which resulted in futexes expiring one second too early until either the machine was rebooted or you ran the workaround:

```
# date -s "`date`"
```

It sounds like you've been bitten by that.

Comment: +1 because this is apparently the most findable-on-SO answer to this problem - which had a couple of us here stumped for a couple of days...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is related to the specific issue but your line:

```
if (ts.tv_nsec > 1000000000)
```

should really be:

```
if (ts.tv_nsec >= 1000000000)
```

And, in fact, if you do something unexpected and pass in 10000 (for example), you may want to consider making it:

```
while (ts.tv_nsec >= 1000000000)
```

though it's probably better at some point to use modulus arithmetic so that loop doesn't run for too long.

Other than that, this appears to be some sort of issue with your environment. The code works fine for me under Debian, `Linux MYBOX 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:01:19 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux`:

```
1343871427.442705862 1343871436.442705862 FIRST
1343871436.442773672 1343871445.442773672 TIMEOUT
1343871445.442832158 1343871454.442832158 TIMEOUT
:
```

One *possibility* is the fact that the system clock is not sacrosanct - it may be modified periodically by NTP or other time synchronisation processes. I mention that as a possibility but it seems a little strange that it would happen in the short time between the timeout and getting the current time.

One test would be to use a different timeout (such as alternating seven and thirteen seconds) to see if the effect is the same (those numbers were chosen to be prime and unlikely to be a multiple of any other activity on the system.

Comment: Trying it on a different kernel shows that it works OK. Using alternating intervals exhibited the same behavior. Strange, but the workaround of using a different kernel is good enough.

Comment: @Joe, I'd still raise a bug against RHEL. All those licensing fees you're no doubt paying for should give you that right at least.